# How to use PushbackInputStream to check array of bytes?

Tags: java, io

I want to check whether the bytes in `ostream` represent a serialized object or an array of bytes:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(ostream);
out.writeObject(new TestClass());
out.flush();
out.close();

byte[] bytes = ostream.toByteArray();
isSerializedObject(new ObjectInputStream(
  new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)))); // returns false
isSerializedObject(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))); // returns true
```

The code for `isSerializedObject` is shown below:

```
public static boolean isSerializedObject(InputStream istream) throws Exception {
  int size = 2;
  PushbackInputStream pis = new PushbackInputStream(istream, size);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
  pis.read(buffer);
  // serialized data can be identified by the following two bytes
  boolean flag = buffer[0] == 0xAC && buffer[1] == 0xED;
  pis.unread(buffer);
  return flag;
}
```

Can someone please explain why `isSerializedObject` returns `false` when I use an `ObjectInputStream` but returns `true` when I use a `ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: Does this have something do with Objects not being (by default) serializeable while byte arrays are? It's not really my area of expertise so I'm not putting this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Why? Just (a) write the byte array with writeObject() instead of write(), and (b) read the object and use 'instanceof' afterwards. Much easier, and it doesn't involve peeking into the protocol.